# Magento - How to create a custom url based on attributes?

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

In the Magento Admin > Catalogue > Attributes > Attribute Sets, we have a set of attributes for "Manufacturers" which group products under designers.

I am trying to create a hyperlink that maps a custom route to an attribute query like so

this is route i want:
{{base_url}}/designers/some-designer-name/

this is what it will map to:
{{base_url}}/?designer=136

I have tried creating a custom url rewrite under Catalogue > URL Rewrite Management with no luck.

Comment: That should redirect to home page.
Try to map it to `{{base_url}}/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?designer=136` instead

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this this may help you

http://www.atwix.com/magento/products-list-cms/

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create custom url, than follow the steps...

> 1. From the Admin panel, **select Catalog >> URL Rewrite Management**
> 2. In the upper-right corner, click the **Add URL Rewrite** button
> 3. In the Add New URL Rewrite section, set Create URL Rewrite to “for Product.”
> 4. Find the product in the list below and click to open the record and click **Skip Category Selection** button
> 5. In the URL Rewrite section, do some following things:
>
> a.In the Request Path field, enter the new value for the updated URL. The Request Path must be unique for each rewrite.
>
> b.Set Redirect to one of the following:
> Temporary (302)
> Permanent (301)
>
> For your own reference, enter a brief description of the rewrite.

click to save and enjoy ;)